# FindAsync(id); doesn't update on screen, only when I refresh the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I started to learn some basic c# and im trying to find my way into ASP.net

I am running the following code with some help from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C5cnZ-gZy2I (time stamp: 1 hour and 50min)

```
    public class BestellenModel : PageModel
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public BestellenModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Bedrijven Bedrijven { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGet(int id)
        {
            Bedrijven = await _db.Bedrijven.FindAsync(id);
        }
    }
}
```

In the video whenever the edit button is pressed the right data from the data base appears on screen. For me nothing appears but whenever i click on my url and hit enter again the data appears.

I tried the debug option within VS and i saw that the line FindAsync doesn't run when hitting the button. But when i click enter on the url then it runs the code. My url looks like this: **https://localhost:7005/Bedrijfslijst/Bestellen?id=32**

Can anyone tell me what i am missing here? because i am a bit stuck.

Edit:

[image: First screen with data]

Now whenever the client Clicks on the "kopen" button it needs to render the data from the db to the fields.

[image]

This is a screenshot from the yt video, its supposed to show the data when the page is loaded. For me its not loading but whenever i click on the url and hit enter then the db data will load in.

[image]

cshtml script:

```
@page
@model test1v1.Pages.Bedrijfslijst.BestellenModel

<br />
<h2 class="text-primary">Rapport bestellen</h2>
<br />

<div class="border container" style="padding:120px;">
    <form method="post">
        <div class="text-danger" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
         <div class="form-group row" style="padding:10px;">
            <div class="col-4">
                    <label asp-for="Bedrijven.Kvk"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <input asp-for="Bedrijven.Kvk" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="Bedrijven.Kvk" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group row" style="padding:10px;">
            <div class="col-4">
                    <label asp-for="Bedrijven.Bedrijfsnaam"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <input asp-for="Bedrijven.Bedrijfsnaam" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="Bedrijven.Bedrijfsnaam" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
           
            <div class="form-group row" style="padding:10px;">
            <div class="col-4">
                    <label asp-for="Bedrijven.Adres"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <input asp-for="Bedrijven.Adres" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="Bedrijven.Adres" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row" style="padding:10px;">
                <div class="col-3 offset-4">
                    <input type ="submit" value="Bestellen" class="btn btn-success form-control" />
                    </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                        <a asp-page="index" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Terug</a>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    @section Scripts{
        <partial name ="_ValidationScriptsPartial"/>
    }
```

Edit2:

```
@page
@model test1v1.Pages.Bedrijfslijst.IndexModel

<br />
<div class="container row p-0 m-0">
    <div class="col-9">
        <h2 class="text-primary">Bedrijf Lijst</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <a asp-page="Zoeken" class="btn btn-primary form-control text-white">Bedrijf Zoeken</a>
    </div>


    <div class= "col-10 border p-4 mt-4">
        <form method="post">
            @if  (Model.Bedrijven.Count() > 0)
            {
                        <table class="table table-striped border">
                    <tr class="table-secondary">
                        <th>
                            <label asp-for="Bedrijven.FirstOrDefault().Kvk"></label>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(m=>m.Books.FirstOrDefault().Author)*@
                            <label asp-for="Bedrijven.FirstOrDefault().Bedrijfsnaam"></label>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <label asp-for="Bedrijven.FirstOrDefault().Adres"></label>
                        </th>
                        <th>

                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach  (var item in Model.Bedrijven)
                    {
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(m=>item.Bedrijfsnaam)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(m=>item.Kvk)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(m=>item.Adres)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <button asp-page="Bestellen" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Kopen</button>
                                                
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                    }
                        </table>
            }
            else
            {
                        <p>Geen Bedrijven Gevonden.</p>
            }
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, this is the normal behavior of a Get.

Comment: Can you please provide the corresponding cshtml ?

Comment: @AbdelkrimBournane i added some screenshots and the cshtml code.

Comment: Ok thanks, I see clearly. I need one more thing, the code snippet of the calling cshtml. The part where there is "Kopen"

Comment: There you go @AbdelkrimBournane

Comment: @AbdelkrimBournane i made such a nooby mistake... i used a <button> but needed to use <a> ... thanks for the help and the respect ;)

Comment: I figured, good luck!